# Query to add one month to the current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can add x number of months to the current month

I have tried below query but it didn't work

```
SELECT DateAdd(month,1,MONTH(GETDATE())) as Month
```

Out
put

```
1900-02-07 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: `DateAdd(month,1,GETDATE())`  You need a date as that third argument. Instead you are converting your date to a month number. Just don't do that.

Comment: What does adding one month to the current **month** mean? Do you want to add one month to the current **date**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return the number for the next month.

```
select MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()))
```

Output:

> 7

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Month(DateAdd(MM,1,GETDATE())) as Month
```

Returns
7

Comment: @Ayman and what should the result be if the current month is December?

Comment: SELECT month(DateAdd(MM,1,GETDATE())) as Month